# How do I add a pause?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am currently trying to make a game and I want one of the features to be when you hit a certain block I called it Obstacle you will pause for 1 second. I just don't know how to add that pause in C#.
The script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {
    public Movememt movement;
         
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision Collisioninfo)
    {           
       if (Collisioninfo.collider.name == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
           // i want the pause here
            movement.enabled = true;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a screenshot of code

Comment: I don't know Unity or Unity scripting but Unity runtime might have a timer mechanism, so create a timer and start that timer when you hit the obstacle, when the required time passed, renable the player state.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

You can change the return value from `void` to `IEnumerator` which will allow you to "pause" by yeilding a new `WaitForSeconds` instance. Here is an example:

```
IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{           
    if (collision.collider.name == "Obstacle")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        movement.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` itself can be a Coroutine btw

Comment: @derHugo I didn't know that, thanks! Updated my answer.

Comment: Or, rather than storing a boolean, create some "disabled until time" value. Are you intending to add other kinds of buffs / debuffs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) with coroutines. For details please go through the link.

> yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

Answer (score -2):

You can pause or resume the game by setting the timescale to 0 or back to 1.

```
void PauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

void ResumeGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
```

Comment: This often has a lot of undesired side effects. Also note that OP already seems to have a mechanism that is supposed to do the trick `movement.enabled = false`

Comment: There is a difference between a pause and a wait

Comment: Exactly .. and if you look at OPs code it is pretty clear that we are not looking for a pause but a wait ;)